# Power BI: Format number with dot instead of comma to separate thousands

Tags: powerbi, formatting, data-visualization, number-formatting

I need to display numbers in power bi using dot as a thousands separator.
**It appears with comma in my computer but when I use other computers to open the same power bi project it appears with a dot.**

How can I get my power bi project to display numbers using dot as a thousands separator instead of comma **in my computer**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mannaged to overcome this issue by changing the language settings in my local machine from English to Portuguese (which is the default language of the computer I'm currently using).